# Why does types.MethodType complain too many arguments?

Tags: python

```
>>> import types
>>> class Foo:
...   def say(self):
...     print("Foo say")
... 
>>> class Bar:
...   def say(self):
...     print("Bar say")
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> b = Bar()
>>> types.MethodType(f.say, b)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: say() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am just wondering what were 2 arguments that I gave? I know one of them would be `self`, but what was the other one?

Of course, in this example, the correct way would be:

```
>>> types.MethodType(Foo.say, b)()
Foo say
```

But I am asking about the error of `types.MethodType(f.say, b)()`. I want to know why  it complains

> takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing this is:

```
import types


class Foo:

    def say(self):
        print("Foo say")


class Bar:

    def say(self):
        print("Bar say")

f = Foo()
b = Bar()
types.MethodType(Foo.say.__func__, b)()
```

You have to **bind** the **function** `Foo.say.__func__` to an instance.

Answer (score 2):

In any method call, the first argument is the object itself as the implicit argument. In your case, the example

```
types.MethodType(f.say, b)()
```

translated to

```
f.say(b)
```

which further translates to

```
say(f, b)
```

so eventually you ended up sending two arguments

Comment: So, how to fix this problem?